# Get Contacts from Phone only android

Tags: android, android-contacts

In my app i need contacts from phone only not from other accounts like gmail and Facebook.With my code i am getting the contacts but issue is that i am getting it from all the sources like gmail ,facebook etc.

Code

```
contactResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                contactsModel = new ContactsModel();

                id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                contactsModel.name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));


                phoneCursor = contactResolver.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);

                while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    // Do something with phones
                    int phoneType = phoneCursor.getInt(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                    String phoneNo = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    //you will get all phone numbers according to it's type as below switch case.
                    switch (phoneType) {
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                            phone = phoneNo;
                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                            phone = phoneNo;
                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                            phone = phoneNo;
                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK_MOBILE:
                            phone = phoneNo;
                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
                            phone = phoneNo;
                            break;
                        default:
                            phone = phoneNo;
                            break;
                    }

                    listPhones.add(phoneNo);
                }


                /*get email*/
                emailCursor = contactResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);

                while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    //String emai = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    int type = emailCursor.getInt(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
                    String s = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.getTypeLabel(context.getResources(), type, "");
                    listEmails.add(emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA)));

                }
                contactsModel.emails = listEmails;
                contactsModel.numbers = listPhones;

                listContacts.add(contactsModel);
                listEmails = new ArrayList<>();
                listPhones = new ArrayList<>();
                emailCursor.close();
                phoneCursor.close();


            }


        }

        cur.close();


        return listContacts;
```

So how will i get the contacts from only phonebook.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "=1", 
            null,
            null
    );
```

where, IN_VISIBLE_GROUP: 1=local, 0=google account

Comment: Thanks but with this code i am getting rid of Gmail contacts but i am still getting hotmail ka contacts

Comment: Sorry but I don't have idea about hotmail.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hope it will help you 


  public void readContacts() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("......Contact Details.....");
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        String phone = null;
        String emailContact = null;
        String emailType = null;
        String image_uri = "";
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                image_uri = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
                if (Integer
                        .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);
                    sb.append("\n Contact Name:" + name);
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        phone = pCur
                                .getString(pCur
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        sb.append("\n Phone number:" + phone);
                        System.out.println("phone" + phone);
                    }
                    pCur.close();

                    Cursor emailCur = cr.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                    while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                        emailContact = emailCur
                                .getString(emailCur
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                        emailType = emailCur
                                .getString(emailCur
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
                        sb.append("\nEmail:" + emailContact + "Email type:" + emailType);
                        System.out.println("Email " + emailContact
                                + " Email Type : " + emailType);

                    }

                    emailCur.close();
                }

                if (image_uri != null) {
                    //System.out.println(Uri.parse(image_uri));
                    try {
                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media
                                .getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),
                                        Uri.parse(image_uri));
                        sb.append("\n Image in Bitmap:" + bitmap);
                      //  System.out.println(bitmap);

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }


                sb.append("\n........................................");
            }

            textDetail.setText(sb);
        }
    }
```